# How to filter or extract or group a list of values comparing with 2 other columns under a condition in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe of 1.3 million rows and a set of columns such as Phone1 (Phone numbers), Sale_date (2015 to 2020), Product_description (185 unique product descriptions) and so on.
Now i want to filter or extract the entire list of phone numbers who have not bought any one of the product (any one product from product_description - let's say table) in year 2020.

```
>>> data.info()**
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 1392125 entries, 0 to 1398844
Data columns (total 25 columns):
 #   Column            Non-Null Count    Dtype         
---  ------            --------------    -----                
 0   Sale_dt            1392125 non-null  datetime64[ns]             
 1   Phone1             1392125 non-null  object               
 2   prod_desc          1392125 non-null  object        
       
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), object(2)
memory usage: 276.1+ MB
```

One more problem is that some of my phone numbers are in scientific notation `(9.96266e+09)` and some of the numbers are having special characters like `044-4578930***`
How to convert all of them to a phone number format?

when i did try to convert to int it throws an error

**data['Phone1'].astype(int)**

**OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long**

when i tried,

**data['Phone1'].astype('int64')**

**ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '22651435,9'**

when i tried to remove special characters from the phone numbers,

**data.Phone1 = data.Phone1.str.replace('[^\d]+', '')
data['Phone1']**

**data['Phone1']**

[image]

```
Out[52]: 
0          NaN
1          NaN
2          NaN
3          NaN
4          NaN
1398840    NaN
1398841    NaN
1398842    NaN
1398843    NaN
1398844    NaN
Name: Phone1, Length: 1392125, dtype: object
```

So, I want to group or extract or filter the phone numbers who have not bought tables (one of the product in prod_desc column) in 2020 but they could have bought any other products in previous years. That doesn't matter.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: How did you load/create this dataframe? You probably want to set a string dtype on the phone column.

Comment: Hi Nick! I load the dataframe using pd.read_csv(r"C:........) 
Can you help me on converting the phone numbers part. 
I have both mobile phone numbers (10 digits) and landline numbers (less than 10 digits). But some landline numbers have special characters (o44-345688). 
So, how can i remove those landline numbers from the column and proceed with the mobile numbers

Comment: Post an example of your CSV? Not the full thing, obviously, just enough to reproduce the problem.